# Stop Server Side GTM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-tag-manager

I am trying to stop server side GTM as I did it for a test to understand the process but I am still getting billed. What are the steps to stop this.

I have so far.

- Removed the transport URL from the GA tag
- Paused the GA tag in the client side GTM
- Removed the 4 A's and 4 AAAA records from my DNS
- Deleted the mapping from the Cloud account under `App Engine > Settings`
- Disabled the application as well

Answer (score 1):

You can find here how to stops it from serving and incurring billing charges related to serving your app:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managing-costs#understanding_billing

Anyway, you may continue to incur charges from other Google Cloud products.

Answer (score 1):

Google Tag Manager has a dependency on App Engine and it requires the [creation of a Google Cloud Platform project](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/serverside#create_a_google_cloud_platform_gcp_server).

In order to stop charges from accruing to an App Engine application you could either [disable the application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/cleaning-up#disabling_your_application) (although some fees related to Cloud Logging, Cloud Storage, or Cloud Datastore might keep being charged), [disable billing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/cleaning-up#disabling_billing) or my recommendation will be to completely [shut down the project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects) related to your tagging server. Take into consideration that when shutting down a project after around 30 days all the resources associated with your project will be fully deleted and you won't be able to recover it.